# python- JSON to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to transform contents from the url which is written in json to pandas dataframe. I can connect to the url and receive contents from the url without any problems, but I am struggling to turn json text to a readable pandas dataframe.

Below is the json I want to transform into pandas dataframe:

```
{'quoteSummary': {'error': None,
  'result': [{'calendarEvents': {'dividendDate': {'fmt': '2018-06-14',
      'raw': 1528934400},
     'earnings': {'earningsAverage': {'fmt': '0.85', 'raw': 0.85},
      'earningsDate': [{'fmt': '2018-04-26', 'raw': 1524700800}],
      'earningsHigh': {'fmt': '0.91', 'raw': 0.91},
      'earningsLow': {'fmt': '0.79', 'raw': 0.79},
      'revenueAverage': {'fmt': '25.77B',
       'longFmt': '25,768,200,000',
       'raw': 25768200000},
      'revenueHigh': {'fmt': '26.35B',
       'longFmt': '26,350,000,000',
       'raw': 26350000000},
      'revenueLow': {'fmt': '25.58B',
       'longFmt': '25,576,000,000',
       'raw': 25576000000}},
     'exDividendDate': {'fmt': '2018-05-16', 'raw': 1526428800},
     'maxAge': 1},
    'defaultKeyStatistics': {'52WeekChange': {'fmt': '36.37%',
      'raw': 0.3636918},
     'SandP52WeekChange': {'fmt': '10.44%', 'raw': 0.10435629},
     'annualHoldingsTurnover': {},
     'annualReportExpenseRatio': {},
     'beta': {'fmt': '1.32', 'raw': 1.322002},
     'beta3Year': {},
     'bookValue': {'fmt': '10.17', 'raw': 10.17},
     'category': None,
     'earningsQuarterlyGrowth': {},
     'enterpriseToEbitda': {'fmt': '19.43', 'raw': 19.428},
     'enterpriseToRevenue': {'fmt': '6.75', 'raw': 6.754},
     'enterpriseValue': {'fmt': '646.02B',
      'longFmt': '646,017,384,448',
      'raw': 646017384448},
     'fiveYearAverageReturn': {},
     'floatShares': {'fmt': '7.59B',
      'longFmt': '7,592,996,725',
      'raw': 7592996725},
     'forwardEps': {'fmt': '3.92', 'raw': 3.92},
     'forwardPE': {'fmt': '23.28', 'raw': 23.283161},
     'fundFamily': None,
     'fundInceptionDate': {},
     'heldPercentInsiders': {'fmt': '1.39%', 'raw': 0.013890001},
     'heldPercentInstitutions': {'fmt': '75.38%', 'raw': 0.75375},
     'lastCapGain': {},
     'lastDividendValue': {},
     'lastFiscalYearEnd': {'fmt': '2017-06-30', 'raw': 1498780800},
     'lastSplitDate': {'fmt': '2003-02-18', 'raw': 1045526400},
     'lastSplitFactor': '2/1',
     'legalType': None,
     'maxAge': 1,
     'morningStarOverallRating': {},
     'morningStarRiskRating': {},
     'mostRecentQuarter': {'fmt': '2017-12-31', 'raw': 1514678400},
     'netIncomeToCommon': {'fmt': '9.54B',
      'longFmt': '9,543,999,488',
      'raw': 9543999488},
     'nextFiscalYearEnd': {'fmt': '2019-06-30', 'raw': 1561852800},
     'pegRatio': {'fmt': '2.30', 'raw': 2.3},
     'priceHint': {'fmt': '2', 'longFmt': '2', 'raw': 2},
     'priceToBook': {'fmt': '8.97', 'raw': 8.974434},
     'priceToSalesTrailing12Months': {},
     'profitMargins': {'fmt': '9.98%', 'raw': 0.09977999},
     'revenueQuarterlyGrowth': {},
     'sharesOutstanding': {'fmt': '7.7B',
      'longFmt': '7,699,789,824',
      'raw': 7699789824},
     'sharesShort': {'fmt': '50.55M',
      'longFmt': '50,550,200',
      'raw': 50550200},
     'sharesShortPriorMonth': {'fmt': '53.33M',
      'longFmt': '53,332,800',
      'raw': 53332800},
     'shortPercentOfFloat': {'fmt': '0.67%', 'raw': 0.0066509997},
     'shortRatio': {'fmt': '2.26', 'raw': 2.26},
     'threeYearAverageReturn': {},
     'totalAssets': {},
     'trailingEps': {'fmt': '1.23', 'raw': 1.23},
     'yield': {},
     'ytdReturn': {}},
    'financialData': {'currentPrice': {'fmt': '91.27', 'raw': 91.27},
     'currentRatio': {'fmt': '2.88', 'raw': 2.885},
     'debtToEquity': {'fmt': '118.92', 'raw': 118.923},
     'earningsGrowth': {},
     'ebitda': {'fmt': '33.25B',
      'longFmt': '33,251,999,744',
      'raw': 33251999744},
     'ebitdaMargins': {'fmt': '34.76%', 'raw': 0.34764},
     'financialCurrency': 'USD',
     'freeCashflow': {'fmt': '10.43B',
      'longFmt': '10,434,124,800',
      'raw': 10434124800},
     'grossMargins': {'fmt': '62.51%', 'raw': 0.62512},
     'grossProfits': {'fmt': '55.69B',
      'longFmt': '55,689,000,000',
      'raw': 55689000000},
     'maxAge': 86400,
     'numberOfAnalystOpinions': {'fmt': '33', 'longFmt': '33', 'raw': 33},
     'operatingCashflow': {'fmt': '41.98B',
      'longFmt': '41,979,998,208',
      'raw': 41979998208},
     'operatingMargins': {'fmt': '25.51%', 'raw': 0.25507998},
     'profitMargins': {'fmt': '9.98%', 'raw': 0.09977999},
     'quickRatio': {'fmt': '2.70', 'raw': 2.702},
     'recommendationKey': 'buy',
     'recommendationMean': {'fmt': '1.80', 'raw': 1.8},
     'returnOnAssets': {'fmt': '6.35%', 'raw': 0.06346},
     'returnOnEquity': {'fmt': '12.97%', 'raw': 0.1297},
     'revenueGrowth': {'fmt': '12.00%', 'raw': 0.12},
     'revenuePerShare': {'fmt': '12.40', 'raw': 12.399},
     'targetHighPrice': {'fmt': '120.00', 'raw': 120.0},
     'targetLowPrice': {'fmt': '62.00', 'raw': 62.0},
     'targetMeanPrice': {'fmt': '104.55', 'raw': 104.55},
     'targetMedianPrice': {'fmt': '105.00', 'raw': 105.0},
     'totalCash': {'fmt': '138.53B',
      'longFmt': '138,534,993,920',
      'raw': 138534993920},
     'totalCashPerShare': {'fmt': '17.99', 'raw': 17.992},
     'totalDebt': {'fmt': '93.19B',
      'longFmt': '93,187,997,696',
      'raw': 93187997696},
     'totalRevenue': {'fmt': '95.65B',
      'longFmt': '95,652,003,840',
      'raw': 95652003840}}}]}}
```

I have tried the following to transform the json into pandas dataframe, but I [this ugly dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFEq.jpg)

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(d["quoteSummary"]["result"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["quoteSummary"]["result"])
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! Do you know how to make the dataframe to have just the raw values of each key? For example, how to have earningsDate to be the column name of the dataframe and the value "raw" to be its value?

Comment: Sorry i am not sure if there is a direct method to do what you need. I would probably modify the JSON to the required format.